# JQuery offset() return negative value with CSS3 column?

Tags: jquery, css, offset

I am the newbie of jQuery. I want to get the top offset of particular element. I use the following method:

```
var top = $("img").offset().top;
```

However, it returns the negative value. I can't understand why it will return the negative value? The smallest value should be zero, or I get anything wrong?

P.S. I use CSS3 column break in the html file.

Thanks a lot!!!

EDIT: The body of html file:

```
<div id="chapter-0">
    <div>
        <h1 xml:lang="en-us" id="toc-anchor">Main Title</h1>
        <h2 xml:lang="en-us" id="toc-anchor-1">Subtitle 1</h2>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <h2 xml:lang="en-us" id="toc-anchor-2">Subtitle2</h2>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <h2 xml:lang="en-us" id="toc-anchor-3">Subtitle3</h2>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/Table-01_fmt.jpeg" alt="Table-01.indd">
    </div>
</div>
```

The code I have used for detecting the height of image:

```
$(\"img\").each(function(i) {
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    alert(top);
}
```

Comment: What's with all the `xml:lang`? `lang` is a valid HTML attribute, why do you need the prefix? Also, why are you trying to escape the quotation marks in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easy to help you if you post the html part where the `img` is and also the CSS applied to it.

EDIT:

I checked the code you posted, and I had syntax errors in the jQuery part, after correcting them I tried both in Firefox and Google Chrome, it works fine.

So can you please try the following html file and see? The only difference is the double-quotes and adding closing bracket that was missing in the jQuery code.

This works in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("img").each(function(i) {
                var top = $(this).offset().top;
                alert(top);
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="chapter-0">
    <div>
        <h1 xml:lang="en-us" id="toc-anchor">Main Title</h1>
        <h2 xml:lang="en-us" id="toc-anchor-1">Subtitle 1</h2>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <h2 xml:lang="en-us" id="toc-anchor-2">Subtitle2</h2>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <h2 xml:lang="en-us" id="toc-anchor-3">Subtitle3</h2>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
        <p xml:lang="zh-hk"> text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/Table-01_fmt.jpeg" alt="Table-01.indd" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I have updated my question with some codes.

Comment: I have added the code I tested. Apart from minor syntax errors it works for me. Check my edited answer.